# Using d3, what is the easiest way to draw a 10000 km2 polygon on a map?

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I would like to illustrate how big different areas are by drawing appropriately sized 'squares' over a map of the UK. See [a non SVG example](http://2050-calculator-tool.decc.gov.uk/pathways/e0d3jrg221ci12110222112004423220444404202304440420141/map) of the idea.

Ideally I'd like to use d3.js to draw the map and the 'squares' using SVG. Ideally I'd like the 'squares' to be polygons that have been appropriately adjusted for the distortion in the map projection.

I get how to draw the map and to project a polygon, so I guess what I'm trying to work out is a javascript function that will take an area, a latitude and a longitude and return a geoJSON polygon that I can then project:

```
function square(area, latitude, longitude) {
   ... something ...
   return geojson_polygon;
}
```

Is this part of any pre-existing library? or can you point me towards some example code that I can crib? or just the maths that I need to implement?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to draw a rectangle as a geojson object; just use your map projection to turn the latitude and longitude into x y coordinates for the svg and draw the rectangles on a separate layer.

To make the rectangle the correct size, you could just eyeball different heights and widths. Alternatively, do a little math (http://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/the-area-bounded-by-geographical-latitude-longitude-points/) to find the latitude and longitude of a rectangle with the correct area, convert those numbers to x y svg coordinates and use those to draw the rectangle.